# Matching up Adjacent columns with Autofill and clear - Error Prompt in Macro

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I wrote a macro that counts rows in two columns, A and B.
If A contains more rows than B (really "B:AK"), then I autofill B:AK down to row A.
BUT if somehow autofill malfunctions or someone messes with the sheet, IF b>a I clear B:AK up to the last row in column A.
[code]
    Sub Autof1ll()

```
Dim lSKUrow As Long
Dim lVOLrow As Long
Dim ix As Integer
Dim iy As Integer
Dim rngFormula As Range

With Workbooks("Raw Data Production").Worksheets("Raw Data")
   lSKUrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lVOLrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rngFormula = .Range("B" & ix & ":AK" & ix)

    ix = lSKUrow
    iy = lVOLrow

If x > y Then
    Workbooks("Raw Data Production").Worksheets("Raw Data").rngFormula.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ix & ":AK" & ix)

Else
    If y > x Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ix + 1 & ":AK" & ix + 1).End(xlDown).Clear
    End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Now I keep getting error prompts and I'm not sure why.
They highlight this portion of the code "Set rngFormula = .Range("B" & ix & ":AK" & ix)"
The error prompt states "Run time error 1004, application or object defined error...

Is there a better way to write this portion of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `ix` before the macro hits the `Set rngFormula` line. Also I don't see `x` or `y` defined anywhere and you use them in if statements.